# How to access a custom Panorama TitleTemplate within c#?

Tags: windows-phone-7

As a title for the Panorama, I use a custom UserControl that I'd like to update from the PhoneApplicationPage. But to do so, I need to access it, I tryed to get the children of the Panorama:

```
Grid grid = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(panorama, 0) as Grid;
```

But it says that panorama has 0 Children. Is it normal? Do you know a way to access a Panorama.TitleTemplate ?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to update the control? Why not update the data-binding, and use a DataTemplate for any eventual layout changes?

Comment: I already use a DataTemplate, but I need to update the DataContext of the UserControl depending of the parameter passed on the OnNavigatedTo.
I can update the datacontext of the Page, but I do not know how to do it for the UserControl, since I cannot access it

Comment: Nothing prevents you from databinding the datacontext to your viewmodel.

Comment: Indeed, I'll do that. Thanks Claus. Nonetheless, it's still strange that the panorama seems to have no children.

Comment: @Hitredin - In what code behind method were you calling `GetChild`? The Panorama may not have initialised yet

Comment: I do this in the method OnNavigatedTo after calling base.OnNavigatedTo(). Indeed during the loaded event, I can access the children of Panorama, and finally access the custom UserControl. Thanks! But I cannot find the control with findName, I have to browse the children from Panorama

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What prevents you from doing this?

```
<controls:Panorama Title="{Binding}">
    <controls:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:MyUserControl DataContext="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
    ...
</controls:Panorama>
```

Comment: If I change the binding of the Title, will it propagate the change in the UserControl? I solved my problem with children browsing but I investigate your way since it's cleaner

Comment: If it's a observable property, then yes, it should. But consider exposing dependency properties on your UserControl, and binding them directly. It's how UserControls are meant to be used.